# Search Value from A column and Paste Value of B in Column D

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table below with details in column A and B. I want to search a string in C from A and paste value of Column B in Column D with help of VBA.

Example:-

```
A         B            C           D 
STRAT   Strategy    s_strat_nhnh  Strategy
TRDMK   Trademarks  bng_trdm_ndnd Trademarks
```

Comment: `trdmk` isn't in `bng_trdm_ndnd`?

Comment: There are so many[INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair examples on this site I cannot even pick one to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Try this formula in D1 and copy down `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(A1),UPPER(C1))),"",B1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRDMK  not in  bng_trdm_ndnd.
But if I got it right, you want something like
[image]

Then Code is:

```
Sub Test()
CStartRow = 1
CEndRow = 5
AStartRow = 1
AEndRow = 3

For I = CStartRow To CEndRow
    For J = AStartRow To AEndRow
        If InStr(UCase(Range("C" + CStr(I))), UCase(Range("A" + CStr(J)))) Then
            Range("D" + CStr(I)) = Range("B" + CStr(J))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next J
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: tried it but VBA code not worked for me. What is C,A D,B in  code. also i want to search it from sheet 1 and paste on sheet 2 . I tried multiple codes but no succeeded.

Comment: Ok. I did some mistake. not saved macro.  But it only works in D1 how to make it work in D1:D

Comment: 1.  C,A D,B - are columns. 2. What is "D1:D" ?

Comment: D1:D is column range. it represent last required cell to be filled.

Comment: So it must be D1:D5 for example. Macro works till row CEndRow. CStartRow = 1, CEndRow = 5. It means D1:D5

Comment: AStartRow = 1,AEndRow = 3 ... Means searched range A1:B3

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use VBA then you can use this formula.
Formula in d1 cell is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,C1)),B1,"")
```

[image: Screenshot]